# Prevent page reload after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm working with WordPress Gravity Forms plugin. I loaded a form into a jquery dialog and I want to have the dialog to close after form submission instead of reloading the page.

However, I don't know, if it is possible to add `preventDefault()` into `submit()` event. Or if there is an option not to reload the page in the Gravity Forms.

Please, advise me a possible way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the Enable AJAX options checked?

Look at https://web.archive.org/web/20150415003507/http://www.gravityhelp.com:80/documentation/gravity-forms/user-guides/getting-started/embedding-a-form/: this will submit your form without a page refresh.

Then just call the dialog close in the submit event and you are done!

Comment: Here is the current documentation: https://docs.gravityforms.com/adding-a-form-using-classic-editor/

Answer (score 2):

You could try targeting an invisible iframe.

```
<form action="this_action.php" method="post" target="iframe">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<iframe name="iframe" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
```

Comment: this method is working well

Answer (score 0):

Making AJAX True along with the shortcode did the trick for me.

```
[gravityform id="2" title="true" ajax="true"]
```